# Sublime Text 2 php endforeach, endif, and endwhile get confused widh html closing tag

Tags: php, sublimetext2, auto-indent

So the problem is basically the autoindent.
I use this in the user configuration for auto indent on f12

`{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }`

And in a somefile.php with html code and php code

```
<div>
    <?php if(something):?>
         hello world
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

F12 results in

```
<div>
    <?php if(something):?>
        hello world
<?php endif;?> //sublime is thinking the endif is a closing html tag.
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change it to:

```
<div>
<?php 
    if(something){
      echo "hello world" // I assume you want to print this line to the screen
    }
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, that works, but the way that <?php endif;?>, <?php endwhile;?> looks, make the code more readable.
Do you know another way to fix this in sublime

Comment: for me, both way of codes are readable.. i don't know why the endif; doen't work.. i'll search for it and let you know